# Excel 2021 .addcomment changing a comment in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

When I execute .addcomment in my VBA code it adds a blank comment to the expected cell but changes the text of a different cell's comment.  I know this sounds crazy but I can recreate it.  I first ran into this in a very large old workbook but now I can make it happen easily in a new workbook.  Can someone with Excel 2021 on Win 11 please try this to see if it's corruption in my computer or something else?
Here are the steps I took:

1. Open a new blank workbook.
2. Manually add a new note to cell B20 (I made the text "This is for B20")
3. Open the Visual Basic editor
4. Right click and add a module in the Project
5. Type in this code:

```
sub add_a_comment()
   activesheet.range("W4").addcomment "This is for W4"
end sub
```

6. run the code.
   When I do this, a blank comment gets added to cell W4 and the comment in B20 gets changed to "This is for W4"
   I have a witness.
   I tried to recreate on a Mac mini running Office 365 and it works as it should.
   I tried to recreate on another almost identical PC (CHUWI Larkbox X 12GB instead of 16GB) running Office 2010 and it works as it should.
   It only does this weird mix up on my CHUWI Larkbox X 16GB with Win 11 and Excel 2021 and it only happens the first time.  After that, if I delete the comment in W4 and run the macro again it works fine.
   I would greatly appreciate any help you can offer!
   Thank you,
   Phil

Comment: Works as expected for me on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Are you using Excel 2021 on Win 11?

Comment: Update: I reinstalled Office 2021 and the weird behavior is the same.  I should also mention that I have the xlwings addin installed.  I'm going to uninstall Office, reinstall, and try again.  Obviously the reinstall did not replace everything.

Comment: Update2: I uninstalled Office and then reinstalled it.  The weird behavior is the same but even with the uninstall and reinstall, the xlwings addin is still there.  I checked the References tab and xlwings is there but not checked.  I looked in File, Options, Add-ins and I don't see xlwings there anywhere yet I still see xlwings in the project window in the Visual Basic editor.  Any ideas how to remove this so I can test a clean install of Office 2021?

Comment: Office 365 on Win10

Comment: Thanks Tim that's a combination I couldn't check.

Comment: Update3: Removed xlwings and problem persists.  Again removed Office 2021 and reinstalled without xlWings.  Problem persists.  Preparing for a total system restore.  While backing up files, 1TB thumb drive became corrupted.  Ran scan and fix.  Deleted incomplete folders as they likely were the ones with corrupted files.  Bitdefender has been installed on this PC since the first day.  Running a full system scan with Bitdefender Total Security.  Will continue to report progress.

Comment: Update4: Total restore of PC.  Deleted all files, cleared disk, set up as new PC.  Installed Firefox and Bitdefender, scanned.  Installed Office 2021.  Problem did not happen!  Was able to insert note in B20, create, run macro to addcomment to W4 and it worked as it should.  Now I'll add other pieces and see if it recurs.  Will run all updates, setup printers, install Adobe reader, Anaconda, and other bits such as Beautiful soup, Selenium, etc,  addin xlwings, copy all files onto PC, run other VBA macros and Python scripts.  After each step I'll test.  After all is done, I'll report back.

Comment: Update5: I have rebuilt my entire PC and the problem is not happening.  There must have been some corruption in a file somewhere.  I have created a restore point so I can return to this working configuration more quickly if it happens again.